# Null return value from functions in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am constantly returning a null value from a function in the fragments that I created dynamically.
I add a liner to the response value returned from Volley.
But when we come to the end of the function, the added data returns to empty.
My codes are as follows;

```
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {
var adapter : MasaListesiAdapter? = null
var IPADRES : String? = null
var BOLUMID : Int? = null
companion object {
    fun newInstance(IPADRES : String, BOLUMID: Int) : BlankFragment{
        val fragment = BlankFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("IPADRES",IPADRES)
        bundle.putInt("BOLUMID",BOLUMID)
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    IPADRES = arguments?.getString("IPADRES")
    BOLUMID = arguments?.getInt("BOLUMID")
    var masalar = masalariGetir(BOLUMID!!.toInt())
    Log.e("MASALAR",masalar.toString()) // İS NULL
}
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
fun masalariGetir(BOLUMID : Int) : ArrayList<MasaBilgileri> {
    var json = JSONObject()
    json.put("BOLUMID",BOLUMID)
    var jsonArray = JSONArray().put(json)
    var responseObje = ArrayList<MasaBilgileri>()
    val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            "http://${IPADRES}/restoway/rwservice/masa",
            jsonArray,
            Response.Listener { response->
                for(satir in 0..response.length()-1){
                    var gecici = MasaBilgileri(response.getJSONObject(satir).getInt("ID"),
                            response.getJSONObject(satir).getInt("BOLUMID"), response.getJSONObject(satir).getString("BOLUMADI"),
                            response.getJSONObject(satir).getInt("MASANO"), response.getJSONObject(satir).getString("MASAADI")
                            )
                    responseObje.add(gecici) // ARRAY ADD PROCESS
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.e("ERROR",error.message)
            }
    ) Singleton.getInstance(context!!).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest)
    Log.e("OBJE",responseObje.toString()) // NULL
    return responseObje
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fun masalariGetir(BOLUMID : Int) : ArrayList<MasaBilgileri> {
    var json = JSONObject()
    json.put("BOLUMID",BOLUMID)
    var jsonArray = JSONArray().put(json)
    var responseObje = ArrayList<MasaBilgileri>()
    val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            "http://${IPADRES}/restoway/rwservice/masa",
            jsonArray,
            Response.Listener { response->
                for(satir in 0..response.length()-1){
                    var gecici = MasaBilgileri(response.getJSONObject(satir).getInt("ID"),
                            response.getJSONObject(satir).getInt("BOLUMID"), response.getJSONObject(satir).getString("BOLUMADI"),
                            response.getJSONObject(satir).getInt("MASANO"), response.getJSONObject(satir).getString("MASAADI")
                            )
                    responseObje.add(gecici) // ARRAY ADD PROCESS
Log.e("OBJE",responseObje.toString()) // SHOULD BE NOT NULL
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.e("ERROR",error.message)
            }
    ) Singleton.getInstance(context!!).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest)

    return responseObje
}}
```

You are trying to access data from an asynchronous function, so if you try to access if after the variable, it might not have finished its work so it might return null, it is not sure and so you have to access it inside.

Comment: I applied the corrections to the project. I specify a log where the return is made and the value looks empty again

Comment: return is made, means, you returned a value inside the response listener? You have to write your code there, after responseObje.add(gecici) // ARRAY ADD PROCESS

Comment: Yes, about 10 to 15 data sets.
I've written the Log tag many times in the jsonArrayRequest field, and I see that the lining element is added.
I see that there is not any element added to the log when I write log tags after jsonArrayRequest.